# Use variable outside of function

Tags: node.js, function

How can I get this object (tempObj) to be available outside of the function)?

The first console.log print it fine, but the other one gives an error that myJSON is not defined...

```
sensor.getAll(function (err, tempObj) {
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(tempObj);
console.log("Objekt "+ myJSON);
});

console.log(myJSON);
```

Comment: is `sensor.getAll` asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, it is async!

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare myJSON outside of the function/closure instead of in it. You can create a variable with global or file scope (ES6) depending on your particular environment.  If you want to use a callback.

```
var myJSON;
function callback() {
    console.log(myJSON);
}
sensor.getAll(function (err, tempObj) {
    myJSON = JSON.stringify(tempObj);
    console.log("Objekt "+ myJSON);
    callback();
});
```

Comment: That's only going to work if `sensor.getAll` is synchronous, but it has the signature of an asynchronous function.

Comment: Correct. myJSON will be undefined until the sensor.getAll is called. You can use a callback inside the getAll function to trigger something to react to myJSON being set

https://benohead.com/blog/2014/12/02/javascript-variables-asynchronous-callback-functions/